# Pandas read_csv with seperators in header names

Tags: python, pandas

i've got a text file similar to this:

```
@ some comment
@ some comment
@ [...]
@ some comment
* NAME   S    BX    BY
bla foo bar foo  
"ACF" 1  2  3
"BGB" 4  5  6
"CSD" 7  8  9
```

I'm using the following to read in the file. Automatic detection of the header seems not possible because the first field `* NAME` contains the column separator in its name.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep="\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+",names=["Name","S","BX","BY"],skiprows=4)
```

1. How to automatically detect the header names?
2. How to remove comments and the `bla...` line below the header?

Answer (score 1):

To automatically detect the header names and clean up the unnecessary lines, you can parse the file line by line, identify the lines you need, and then create the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import re

filename = 'test.txt'

def parse_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    data_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if not line.startswith('@') and not line.startswith('bla')]

    header_line = next(line for line in data_lines if line.startswith('*'))
    columns = re.split('\s+', header_line.strip('*').strip())[0:]  
    print(columns)
    
    data_lines.remove(header_line)
    
   
    data = [re.split('\s+', line) for line in data_lines]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    
    return df

df = parse_file(filename)

print(df)
```

final output

```
NAME  S BX BY 
"ACF"  1  2  3
"BGB"  4  5  6 
"CSD"  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

For your *specific* example, you could do this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\s\s+|(?<=")\s',skiprows=4,engine='python').dropna()
```

This uses a separator of either multiple spaces (which works for the header, and most of the data) or a space preceded by a double quote (which works for the `"ABC"` values.

Since the `bla foo bar foo` line only has one value when using that separator, we can drop it using `dropna`.

Output for your sample input:

```
  * NAME    S   BX   BY
1  "ACF"  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  "BGB"  4.0  5.0  6.0
3  "CSD"  7.0  8.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - get all lines that start with `*` or with `"` and then use `pd.read_csv`:

```py
from io import StringIO

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = []
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        if line.startswith(("*", '"')):
            lines.append(line)

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO("\n".join(lines)),
    sep=r"\s{2,}|(?<=\") ",
    engine="python",
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  * NAME  S  BX  BY
0  "ACF"  1   2   3
1  "BGB"  4   5   6
2  "CSD"  7   8   9
```